# Device names on hotswap server. (Name by port rather than insert order?)

Tags: linux, udev

Is there a way to name devices such that any drive plugged into slot 1 is always named /dev/sda? Rather than just first drive inserted sda even though it's plugged into the last slot, second sdb wherever it goes, etc...

Edit (after more research):
How does /dev/disk/by-path work? Does part of the name map to a physical port?

Edit again:
by-path does not seem to work at all with the hotswap drives. They do not show up.

Comment: I need a way to distinguish ports. So that my program can alert that the drive in port __ is ready to be removed.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than rely on device names being always the same, why not use filesystem labels? Those are a *lot* easier to deal with.

To set a label on a partiton (ext2/3/4 in this case):

```
$ e2label /dev/sda1 FOOBAR
```

Then in `/etc/fstab`:

```
LABEL=FOOBAR     /mnt/foobar    ext3   defaults 0 0
```

Comment: UUIDs are good too, though more painful to read.

Comment: These drives will only be plugged in once for a few hours before a completely new drive comes in.  Will this map the physical location of the drive or the drive itself?

Comment: This will give the kernel a clue as to where to mount the drive when it's presented, regardless of physical slot.

Comment: It will label a device, not a port.

Comment: I need a way to distinguish ports. So that it can alert that the drive in port __ is ready to be removed. Without writing specific information about each drive before plugging it in.