# Access a drive by port, rather than /dev/

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Device names on hotswap server. (Name by port rather than insert order?)](https://serverfault.com/questions/415228/device-names-on-hotswap-server-name-by-port-rather-than-insert-order)

I need a way to access the drive in sata port *??* on a hotswappable server.  I was previously trying to access by a /dev/ name and find the port it belongs to but I cannot seem do that.
The drives will basically be assembly lined through the server so I can not do anything drive specific (rename by uuid etc...).

I will need to be able to use hdparm and dd on the drive.

Comment: No that was about renaming the drive as it comes in, this is about accessing the drive by port.

Comment: Nice username btw, I have a copy of the breakfast poster not ten feet away from me.

Comment: For better or worse, names on the SE sites aren't unique.  I am but one of many Charleses, for example.

Comment: I probably should have noticed that ha ha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On most modern distros, you'll have a `/dev/disk` directory.  Inside will be a handful of other directories, each corresponding to one way to find a disk device.

Inside `by-id`, you'll see drives and partition "names" as made up by the kernel.  Usually these names will include the disk model number and serial number.  For example, a name I have on one of my systems is `scsi-SATA_ST3808110AS_5LR187B2` is a SCSI (SATA) Seagate ST3808110AS with the serial number 5LR187B2.

Inside `by-label`, you'll see *partition* labels, [as discussed in your earlier question](https://serverfault.com/questions/415228).  You might not have labels, and they're for partitions, not drives.

Inside `by-path`, you'll see path name built from the chain of devices that lead to the device.  For example, I have one called `pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-3:0:0:0` -- the fourth (counting from zero) SCSI device attached to a SCSI adapter attached to the PCI bus.

Finally, `by-uuid` contains the UUIDs assigned to each *partition* on the available drives.

*All* of these are simple symlinks back to the appropriate device in /dev.

If you're trying to find a device on a specific SATA port, using the device names in `by-path` is probably going to work for you.

Comment: Is there a way to make by-path work with hot-swapped sata drives? For some reason it works with usb, but not the sata.

Comment: @DukeSilver, at least on the systems I'm working with here (CentOS 5 and 6), hot-swap drives appear correctly inside the `/dev/disk` hierarchy.  The device names I gave above are hot-swap devices on that machine.

Comment: For some reason the contents of by-path do not change when I add drives to the system. Every other folder seems to change, but not by-path.
Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Hmm.  Well, the node *names* in there won't change, but do the drive letters that they point at change?  I'm assuming that `by-id` changes, right?  Given that the names in there are generated based on the model and serial of the drive, I'd certainly hope so.  You can use the combined data between the two to derive the port number for any given disk device.  Don't forget that hot-swaps are likely to appear in your syslog.

Comment: (If it isn't clear, you can watch `by-id` for changes, look up the device it points to, then look in `by-path` for the name in there that points at the same device; the `by-path` name will contain the actual port number the drive is attached to, and you get the serial number of the device for free!  Given that you seem to be doing something like drive testing here (assumption), having that information available to you easily may be very useful.)

Comment: the problem is that by-path list all the usb connections fine but only has 1 entry other than usb and it is 0:0:0:0 or something like that.  How do I use the syslog?

Comment: Found dmesg, I'm going to go see what it brings up on the server, because the usb here keeps incrementing each time I add it.
 (34:0:0:0, 35:0:0:0, 36:0:0:0 etc...)

Comment: You can find `syslog` in /var/log.  On some distros, it's called `messages` instead.  `dmesg` is for *boot* messages.  Same thing, really, just the others get updated.

Comment: @Charles, dmesg is for more then just boot processes.  The dmesg command displays the kernel ring buffer.  Basically anything the kernel wants to log.  When the system boots, this has the messages from when the kernel loads, but if your system is up long enough and it is active enough the boot messages will fall out of the list to be replaced by other kernel messages.

Comment: So I found this sas_addr in the log and it has a pointer 0x122100000[port number] and then some more zeroes.  Is this safe to use or will this number change when the system is booted/updated/changed in any way?

Comment: Because once again the num:num:num:num just keeps incrementing whenever a drive changes

Comment: @DukeSilver, unfortunately I'm out of suggestions.  I've never actually had to do more than one hot-swap at a time to test what happens...

Comment: @Zoredache, thank you for your information, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: That's ok you gave me a lot to work with by telling me to check the logs.  For these systems I may have to hardcode the port address (0x12....) in my software until I find a more portable solution.
Thank you

Comment: That number even stayed the same when I used another boot disk in the machine so I think I can manage off of that.